# jQuery Mobile and Google Analytics

Tags: jquery-mobile, google-analytics

I've seen lots of posts that explain how to integrate Google analytics with your JQM site, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.
I'm using JQM version 1.2 and have an external javascript file containing this code:

> var _gaq = _gaq || [];
>   _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12345678-9']);
>
> (function() {   var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type =
>   'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;   ga.src = ('https:' ==
>   document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') +
>   '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';   var s =
>   document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
>   s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s); })();
>
> $('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
>       try {
>           hash = location.hash;
>           if (hash && hash.length > 1) {
>               _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', hash.substr(1)]);
>           } else {
>               _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
>           }
>       } catch(err) {
>       } });

Can you spot why this isn't working?
Do I need to load the code inline on each page rather than have it in an external file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to trigger page views to the "pageshow" event.

See: http://roughlybrilliant.com/jquery_mobile_best_practices#7

Try this:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];

    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        (function() {
          var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
          ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + 
              '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
          var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
}); 

    $('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
        try {
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'YOUR_ANALYTICS_ID_GOES_HERE']);

            if ($.mobile.activePage.attr("data-url")) {
                _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', $.mobile.activePage.attr("data-url")]);
            } else {
                _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
            }
        } catch(err) {}

    });
```

If you put the above code in an external file, be sure that the code will be run in the right time (after JQM and the page is loaded)... better attach this code to the end of your main html file.

Comment: Thanks Ude, but I still can't get it working. I've tried adding the document ready section in the <head> section of my pages, and the pageshow section just before the closing <body> tag but still can't see anything in analytics. I've changed the _gaq.push line to _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', $.mobile.activePage.attr("data-url") + '-Mobile']); so I can identify the pages in analytics by the '-Mobile' extension

Comment: Ignore me, I've just checked analytics and there's lots of pages with the '-Mobile' suffix so it looks like everything is working.....it just takes a day for the analytics to show! Thanks again Ude

Comment: [An amended solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18736218/315024) (for jQuery Mobile 1.3) now that `live` does not exist in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];

    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        (function() {
          var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
          ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + 
                  '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
          var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    }); 

    $('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
        try {
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'YOUR_ANALYTICS_ID_GOES_HERE']);

            if ($.mobile.activePage.attr("data-url")) {
                _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', $.mobile.activePage.attr("data-url")]);
            } else {
                _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
            }
        } catch(err) {}

    });
```

warn: **live** method renamed to **on**

Could be a seperate file injected into your (php, jsp) page

**and** you must inject it just before closing div of data-role page

You can check jquery mobile best practices and more specific
See: http://roughlybrilliant.com/jquery_mobile_best_practices#7

Comment: `on` is not a drop-in replacement for `live`.